# Output not aligned correctly even after using SetW

Tags: c++

I want my program to be aligned correctly; I'm using the iomanip (setw) library but I'm still getting the wrong output:

[image: The output I'm getting]

The output I want is:

```
1001 Butter         9.45  50  100 74
1002 Milk-1L        12.85 100 150 83
1003 Flour-Bak      13.45 210 500 410
```

The output I'm getting currently is:

```
1001 Butter      9.45  50  100 74
1002 Milk-1L       12.85 100 150 83
1003 Flour-Bak        13.45 210 500 410
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Function Declaration
void displaymenu();
void Inventory();
void empgrossnet();
void employavgdeduc();

// Size of Array
const int SIZE = 10;
int i;

// Initialize Struct function for Employee Data
struct InventoryData {
  int Itemnum;
  string Name;
  double UnitPrice;
  int Minimumlevel;
  int Optimumlevel;
  int Qtyinstock;

} InventoryItems[SIZE];

// Initialize/Read file into the program
ifstream thefile("i_Data.txt");

int main() {

  while (true) {
    displaymenu();
  }
  return 0;
}

void displaymenu() {
  int option;

  // print menu options and prompt user to enter a menu option
  printf("\n***************** Employee Data *******************\n");
  printf("[1] Press 1 for Inventory  Data Records\n");
  printf("[2] Press 2 for Employee Gross and Net Pay\n");
  printf("[3] Press 3 for Average Hours and Average Deductions\n");
  printf("[4] Exit Program\n");
  printf("\n****************************************************\n");
  printf("\n Enter an option>>\t");
  scanf("%d", &option);

  switch (option) {
  case 1:
    Inventory();
    break;

  case 4:
    printf("\n\n Thank you for using the Program");
    printf("\n Exiting Application....");
    exit(0);
  }
}

void Inventory() {

  // Read from edata.txt File
  ifstream thefile("i_Data.txt");

  // Check to make sure that Program is finding/reading from edata file
  if (!thefile) {
    cerr << "File can't be opened! " << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    exit(1);
  }

  // Creat loop to store 5 lines of information from edata file
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    thefile >> InventoryItems[i].Itemnum >> InventoryItems[i].Name >>
        InventoryItems[i].UnitPrice

        >> InventoryItems[i].Minimumlevel >> InventoryItems[i].Optimumlevel >>
        InventoryItems[i].Qtyinstock;
  }

  // Output/Display Edata file information into prgram
  printf("\n************************************* EMPLOYEE DATA "
         "****************************************\n");
  printf("\n %s %15s %20s %15s %15s ", "EmployeeID", "Employee Name",
         "Hours Worked", "Rate of Pay", "Deductions");
  printf("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------"
         "------------------\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    cout << setw(10) << " " << InventoryItems[i].Itemnum;
    cout << setw(10) << " " << InventoryItems[i].Name;
    cout << setw(10) << " " << InventoryItems[i].UnitPrice;
    cout << setw(10) << " " << InventoryItems[i].Minimumlevel;
    cout << setw(10) << " " << InventoryItems[i].Optimumlevel;
    cout << setw(10) << " " << InventoryItems[i].Qtyinstock << endl;
  }
  printf("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------"
         "------------------\n");
}
```

Comment: Could you use some consistent indentation?

Comment: See the console.log example for how to easily create a code block with no need to add 4 spaces before the text: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: `std::setw` only applies to the next insertion.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want

```
cout <<" " << setw(10) << InventoryItems[i].Itemnum;
cout <<" " << setw(10) << InventoryItems[i].Name;
cout <<" " << setw(10) << InventoryItems[i].UnitPrice;
cout <<" " << setw(10) << InventoryItems[i].Minimumlevel;
cout <<" " << setw(10) << InventoryItems[i].Optimumlevel;
cout <<" " << setw(10) << InventoryItems[i].Qtyinstock<<endl;
```

Your original code outputs 10 spaces then values. I believe you want single spaces and values in 10-char placeholders.